# Redux Reselect - selector with argument input is recalculating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, reselect

I have the following selector:

```
const getAllAddresses = (withStartEnd) => 
    createSelector(
        [getAllAddressesSelector, getStartAddressSelector, getEndAddressSelector],
        (all, startAddress, endAddress) => {
            if (!withStartEnd) return [...Object.values(all)];
            return [startAddress, ...Object.values(all), endAddress];
        }
    );
```

I noticed that the selector is re-calculating every time, event when `all`, `startAddress` and `endAddress` do not change. If I remove the input for the selector function, to something like this:

```
const getAllAddresses = (
    createSelector(
        [getAllAddressesSelector, getStartAddressSelector, getEndAddressSelector],
        (all, startAddress, endAddress) => {
            return [startAddress, ...Object.values(all), endAddress];
        }
    )
);
```

Then everything works as expected and the selector does not re-calculate on every call. Seems like I missing something in the selector concept. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

Please refer to [How do I create a selector that takes an argument?](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#q-how-do-i-create-a-selector-that-takes-an-argument)

In short: the way you did it, will work only if you pass static arguments and create a factory function outside of `mapStateToProps`. For dynamic arguments it's more complex and please follow the resource I already mentioned above.

The reason your selector is recalculated each time `mapStateToProps` is called is that calling `getAllAddresses` will create a new instance of `createSelector` and the memoization won't work.

---

**Original answer:**

In short, `reselect` determines input selector changes, based on identity check `===`.

Therefore, if your input selectors always create and return a new object or array, then your selector will be recalculated each time.

In order to fix the recalculation issues:

1. Make sure your input selectors always return a reference, instead of new object / array.
2. Or, if a new object / array is the proper returned value, then you have to [customize the equalityCheck for defaultMemoize](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#customize-equalitycheck-for-defaultmemoize)

From the `reselect` docs:

[**Why is my selector recomputing when the input state stays the same?**](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#q-why-is-my-selector-recomputing-when-the-input-state-stays-the-same) (please follow the link, there are great examples)

> Check that your memoization function is compatible with your state update function (i.e. the reducer if you are using Redux). For example, a selector created with createSelector that recomputes unexpectedly may be receiving a new object on each update whether the values it contains have changed or not. createSelector uses an identity check (===) to detect that an input has changed, so returning a new object on each update means that the selector will recompute on each update.

Comment: Thanks @Jordan. But why in my second example it does not recalculate? I also create a new array every time. The only difference is that the first example except an input, which the second one does not. What am I missing?

Comment: You're welcome. Please refer to my updated answer. Thanks!